# C++ cout not accepting strings or strings with +

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cout

```
class Book {
public:
    string title;
    string author;

    void readBook() {

        cout << "Reading" + this->title + " by " + this->author << endl;
    }
};
```

This is causing the following error.

```
binary '<<': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>'
```

Secondly

```
cout << part1 << endl;
```

This is causing this error.

```
Error C2679 binary '<<': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'std::string'
```

My include statements

```
#include <string>
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <exception>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h>
using namespace std;
```

All in VS 2017.

I can get the strings to print with

```
cout << part1.c_str() << part2.c_str() << endl;
```

Can someone explain to me why it won't print the strings without `.c_str()` and why it won't accept multiple strings? I am following a tutorial and the tutor is able to process these variables without error.

Comment: Can't reproduce with a [mcve]. See https://ideone.com/yKq4yi.

Comment: Something has gone very wonky there if the `op<<` is not in scope. Present a [mcve].

Comment: The `#include <string>` should be _after_ the `#include "pch.h"`.

Comment: Visual studio totally ignores anything typed before #include precompiled headers.

Comment: What is in pch.h - we are assuming it is a precompiled header but is it?

Answer (score -3):

`cout << somethig` is implemented by operator overloading..

`operator <<( const char * )` is exist..

but `operator <<( string )` is not exist..

`c_str()` returns `const char *`. so, You can use it with `cout <<`

This will work..

`cout << "Reading" << this->title.c_str() << " by " << this->author.c_str() << endl;`

Comment: OP already pointed out they know they can use `c_str()` to get it to work. `operator<<(std::string)` _does_ exist: it exists the `<string>` header which OP has included

Comment: @Tas Please, look at the error message.. it says it is not exist..